# Syncfusion Sftoast not showing notification

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, syncfusion

I am creating a blazor project where I use syncfusion components. I wanna use Sfnotification when a user is sending data to say that the data was succesfully sended, the think it is that I can never see that notification. I literally copy & pasted the object from the oficial documentation and added to my project.

My project is composed with a form.razor and form.razor.cs

On the form.razor I have an Editform that uses an OnValidSubmit = SendFunction with the sftoast

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor;

<Editform Model="model" OnValidSubmit="ShowNotification">
        <div class="mb-8">
            <label class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Titulo</label>
            <SfTextBox @bind-Value="@model.name"></SfTextBox>
        </div>
<button>Submit</button>
</Editform>

<SfToast @ref="@ToastObj" Content=" La informacion se ha enviado correctamente" Timeout="5000">
    <ToastPosition X="Right" Y="Top"></ToastPosition>
</SfToast>
```

Now in the back code I have declared an object called in this way:

```
public partial class Form
{

private Model model = new();

public SfToast? ToastObj;

public async Task ShowOnClick()
  {
      await Task.Delay(100);
      // Show the toast
      await this.ToastObj.ShowAsync();

  }

}
```

I know that syncfusion is correctly installed on the project bc I use anothers components that works.

Comment: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/toast/getting-started
https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/Blazor-Getting-Started-Examples/tree/main/Toast

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial and registered the service?

Comment: Yes, I have it already. Up I said that Im using anothers syncfusion components and I don't have any issues. @maciek

Comment: Then I am afraid there is not enough info to help you out. If you clone the repo, does the example work?

Comment: The example works. I have something on my code that doesn't let me see the notification.

Comment: @maciek I just found it. I reinstalled all the package NuGets from syncfusion and worked...